# Nikon D3000 70-300 Nikon lens - How to get lens converter off the lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting, teleconverter

I put a Vivitar tele converter on my 70-300 lens. It went on easy but wont come off. How do I get the thing to come off my lens? I have a Nikon D3000 camera.

Comment: Is the teleconverter attached to the camera? From the wording of your question, I gather not, and so the camera doesn't matter, correct? Teleconverters have a push switch to disengage the lock on the lens, just like the camera does to remove the lens. Can you push the lock and not rotate the lens, or can you not push the lock? More information is needed. Perhaps even a pic.

Comment: Is this a teleconverter that attaches between the camera and lens? Or a a magnifying lens that attaches to the filter threads on the front of the lens?

Answer (score 1):

The teleconverter locks onto the lens just the camera body does and it features a switch that you can push in order to release the lens again by twisting. I don't know what exact model of a teleconverter, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhiqqFIfgwE#t=93) features a Vivitar teleconverter for Nikon. The link will start the video at the 1.33 mark with the teleconverter's lens release nob clearly visible at the left hand side of the frame.

If you already know about the switch but can't press it down for some reason (as Dan suggested could be the case in the comment) please send a picture so that we at least have a chance to assess the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already given it a good twist it is likely the lens mount is jammed at the locking stud. Twist it firmly in the "on" direction, then press the release button and try to remove it again.

It will come off easily. If it doesn't, there's a reason. Applying any excess force will likely just break something, and "something" in the same sentence as "Nikon" usually equals "expensive"